# Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js

Tags: angular, grails-2.0

I'm trying to run a Grails 2.3.9 application that use inside Angular 5. For this i create a new Grails project and a new angular project with *angular-cli* (`ng new app`). After this i made these steps.

1. Build the angular project to get the resources bundles: `ng build --prod`
2. Copy the already created dist folder's files and paste it in the Grails project in *web-app/js/lib*
3. In grails create a new Controller and view to serve the index for angular
4. In the *index.gsp* i put the content of the *index.html* that was created in angular build and replace the src of the scripts with Grails create link statements pointing to js/lib/... to be able for Grails to serve correctly those files

When I run my Grails app and go to the specified address for angular to run I get a blank page and in the console this error:

```
Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
```

I try to copy the dist folder in an Apache server and everything works fine, so, i don't think that the problem is related to the generated files after `ng build --prod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i figure it out, the problem was the way that i was referencing the angular js resources in the `index.gsp`:

**Wrong way**

index.gsp

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <app-root></app-root>
     <script src="${createLink(uri:'js/lib/inline.bundle.js')}"</script>
     <script src="${createLink(uri:'js/lib/polyfills.bundle.js')}"</script>
     <script src="${createLink(uri:'js/lib/main.bundle.js')}"</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Correct way**

ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
  ...
  angular{
    resource url:"js/lib/styles.bundle.css", nominify:true, disposition: 'head'
    resource url:"js/lib/inline.bundle.js", nominify:true
    resource url:"js/lib/polyfills.bundle.js", nominify:true
    resource url:"js/lib/main.bundle.js", nominify:true
  }
}
```

index.gsp

```
<html>
   <head>
     ...
     <r:require modules="angular"/>
     <r:layoutResources/>   
   </head>
   <body>
     <app-root></app-root>
     <r:layoutResources/>
   </body>
</html>
```

The correct way to add resources in grails 2 was found [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/index.html)